# Resize Dojox.Calendar

Tags: javascript, calendar, dojo

I'm using Dojo 1.8 to create a calendar (`dojox/calendar/calendar`). However, I don't think it is made clear in the [development reference](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/calendar.html), [API doc](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/#1_8dojox_calendar_Calendar), or [the demo](http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/calendar/demo.html) on how to **resize the main calendar**.

Actually, my main objective is to be able to add more displayable events to a cell, rather than resort to the [extension button](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/_images/expandRenderer.png). How is this achieved?

Comment: I understood there are `HorizontalRenderer`, `VerticalRenderer`, and `SecondarySheet`, but making use of them is still not clear to me.

Comment: which view, month, day 6month?